# Why is the @@ROWCOUNT variable returning zero after the IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a simple code referring to the pubs database. The SELECT statement returns 10 records so @@ROWCOUNT variable should be set to 10. But how come in the message window, it says '0 records found'. Is there a reason why after an IF statement @@ROWCOUNT is set to 0?

If I put SELECT @@ROWCOUNT right after the WHERE statement, the @@ROWCOUNT variable is at 10. But it changes after executing the IF STATEMENT.

```
SELECT *
FROM pubs.dbo.employee
WHERE pub_id ='0877' 

IF   @@ROWCOUNT > 0
     PRINT CONVERT(CHAR(2), @@ROWCOUNT) + ' records found'
ELSE
    PRINT 'No records found'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 3):

`@@ROWCOUNT` returns the row count for the last statement.  It is highly volatile.  So, basically, anything can reset it.

If you care about it, assign it to a parameter immediately!

```
DECLARE @ROWCNT INT;

SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.employee WHERE pub_id = '0877';
SET @ROWCNT = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Then use the parameter value.